# Android altBeacon sometimes I get a beacons at 5 sek

Tags: android, altbeacon

This is my activity :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier {

    private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this.getApplicationContext());
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);
        try {
            mBeaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mBeaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        Region region = new Region("all-beacons-region", null, null, null);
        try {
            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mBeaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        Log.e("beacon size" , beacons.size() + "");
        for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                // This is a Eddystone-UID frame
                Identifier namespaceId = beacon.getId1();
                Identifier instanceId = beacon.getId2();
                Log.e("Beacon ", beacon.getBluetoothName() +" id: " + namespaceId +
                        " id2: " + instanceId +
                        " id3 " + beacon.getId3());

                // Do we have telemetry data?
                if (beacon.getExtraDataFields().size() > 0) {
                    long telemetryVersion = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(0);
                    long batteryMilliVolts = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(1);
                    long pduCount = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(3);
                    long uptime = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(4);


                }
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
    }
}
```

And a didRangeBeaconsInRegion get me sometimes a beacons array = 0 . Why ? I have a wait sometimes 3-4 sec to get not 0 size array .

sometimes I have to wait a bit to get a non-empty becons board and I don't know why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- Not 100% of transmitted beacons get received.  Reasons for missed detections include radio noise and collisions.  Typically, 80-90% of transmissions are received at close range (fewer at greater distances) and fewer with weak receivers.
- Although 80 percent may sound like a high success rate, the law of averages means that there will sometimes be long periods where you don't get a detection.  This is similar to flipping a coin and getting heads 10 times in a row.  It happens.
- Different beacons advertise at different rates.  Apple recommends a 10 Hz transmitter, but lots of beacon manufacturers slow this down to 1Hz or less to save battery life.  Unfortunately, infrequent transmission will lead to more frequent problems like described here.  If you can, set your beacon to a 10 Hz transmission rate.  If you do not know your beacon's transmission rate, you can use my [BeaconScope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner&hl=en_US) app to analyze your beacon, and give a received PPS (packets per second) score.  Note: the PPS score on this app will always be a bit less than the actual advertising rate because some packets are lost in receipt as described above.
- Different phones scan with different "scan windows", especially in the background.  Samsung phones, for example, will at times switch to a low power scan in the background that scans for 0.5 seconds every 10 seconds in the background, even though the app has told it to scan constantly.  Other OEMs have similar optimizations.  This reduces the frequency of detections, because the receiver must be on when the beacon transmitter sends its advertisement.